# How to prove that $T(x)=[x]_a$ is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\alpha=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Let $T:\ V\to \Bbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(x)=[x]_a$ for every $x\in V$. How to show that $T$ is surjective (onto). Here $[v]_a$ is the coordinate vector for $v$. i.e. $v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$. Then $[v]_a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$

My try:

Let $y\in \Bbb{R}^n$. Since every vector in $V$ can be uniquely represented by linear combination of $\alpha$ basis vectors, the coordinate numbers of $x$ are not all same. Therefore $\forall y\in \Bbb{R}^n, \exists x\in V$ such that $T(x)=y$

Alternative solution:

We can represent the transformation in a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\ldots\\0&1&0&\ldots\\0&0&1&\ldots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{bmatrix}$. Since it has full rank, so the transformation is surjective.

But I feel neither of my solution is valid. Could someone suggest a good one?

Comment: Can you state explicitly what you mean by $[x]_a$?  Is it the $a$th component of the vector $x$ in the basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$?

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: Even with your edit this is still not clear.  Don't you want $T:V \to \mathbb{R}^n$?  The tuple (which right now has final subscript $2$) belongs to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some supposed $k$.  $T$ can't be real-valued.

Comment: Sorry, it is $\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: For any $n$-tuple $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ you can construct the vector $v = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n \in V$, and this satisfies $T(v) = a$.

Comment: Let $y\in \Bbb{R}^n$, then $y=(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)$. Note that $w=a_1 v_1+\cdots +a_n v_n   \in V$. Therefore $T(w)=y$.

Answer (score 4):

To show that $T : V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is surjective, you need to show that for every $(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Having chosen $(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you can let $v = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n$, so that $T(v)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Thus, $T$ is surjective.